# how to extract particular categories in a variable from a dataframe in python

Tags: python

I have a dataframe like below and from the below data, I want to extract where the user_category is 1,2,4,6 as transactional data and where the user_category is 3 as promotional data

textdata

```
id   user_category   operator   circle  
23       1           vodafone   mumbai  
45       2           airtel     andhra  
65       3           airtel     chennai  
23       6           vodafone   mumbai  
45       1           airtel     gurgaon  
65       2           airtel     ongole  
23       4           vodafone   mumbai  
45       1           airtel     telangana  
65       3           airtel     chennai
```

This is how i tried for that,i got the output how i want but what i need is how can extract the data where the user_category is 1,2,4,6 in a single piece of code

```
transactional1 = textdata[textdata['user_category'] == 1]
transactional2 = textdata[textdata['user_category'] == 2]
transactional3 = textdata[textdata['user_category'] == 4]
transactional4 = textdata[textdata['user_category'] == 6]
transactional = pd.concat((transactional1, transactional2,
                       transactional3, transactional4))

promotional = textdata[textdata['user_category'] == 3]
```

expected way:

```
transctional = textdata[textdata['user_category'] == 1,2,4,6]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is with the `isin` method, which mimics the python `1 in [1,2,3]` sort of behavior:

```
transctional = textdata[textdata['user_category'].isin([1,2,4,6])]
```

There are other ways to do this, but they are less clear and more verbose.